# How to get region_id value inside collectRates method from shipping module : Magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, magento-2.1.3

I am working on shopping cart custom shipping method.
I am using the following link http://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/.

`estimate-shipping-method` ajax call having *region_id* and I need that value inside `collectRates()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for it.

```
$request->getDestRegionId();
```

It gives the region id.

Answer (score 1):

If you `var_dump($request->getData())` you will see that there are all details available in it.
To get `region_id` simply use,

```
$regionId = $request->getData('region_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$region = $data['region_id'];
```

this is uncommon way, but it works